# Multiplicación de Matrices en java

Tags: java

Me podrían ayudar con un problema, tengo que hacer una multiplicación entre dos matrices, como ven en el código mando a llamar otras clases que ya tengo hechas hacen (suma, multiplicación de racionales) de racionales ya que los valores son racionales

```
Matriz res = new Matriz (m1.getFilas(),m1.getColumnas());
Racional r1 = new Racional();
Operaciones o = new Operaciones ();
if(m1.getFilas()== m2.getColumnas()){
    for (int i = 0; i <m1.getColumnas(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <m2.getFilas(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m1.getColumnas(); k++) {
                r1 = Suma(r1,o.Multiplicacion(m1.getElemento(i, k), m2.getElemento(k, j)));
                res.setElemento(i, j, r1);   
            }
        }         
    }     
} else {
    System.out.println("No se puede realizar la multiplicacion");
}
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Hola, me gustaría ayudarte, tienes que decirme cual es problema que ocurre cuando corres este codigo

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay un ejemplo para matrices n x n:

```
   public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // #1
        double[][] matriz1 = new double[][] { { 2 }, { -1 } };
        double[][] matriz2 = new double[][] { { 3, 5 } };
        System.out.println("#1\n"
                + toString(multiplicacionMatrices(matriz1, matriz2)));
        // #2
        matriz1 = new double[][] { { 1, 2, 0 }, { -1, 3, 1 }, { 2, -2, 1 } };
        matriz2 = new double[][] { { 2 }, { -1 }, { 1 } };
        System.out.println("#2\n"
                + toString(multiplicacionMatrices(matriz1, matriz2)));
        // #3
        matriz1 = new double[][] { { 1, 2, -1 }, { 0, 1, 0 } };
        matriz2 = new double[][] { { 1, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 2, 1, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 2, 2 } };
        System.out.println("#3\n"
                + toString(multiplicacionMatrices(matriz1, matriz2)));
    }

    public static double[][] multiplicacionMatrices(double[][] m1, double[][] m2) {
        int m1ColLength = m1[0].length;
        int m2RowLength = m2.length;
        // VALIDACIÓN MULTIPLICACIÓN DE MATRICES
        if (m1ColLength != m2RowLength)
            return null;
        int mRRowLength = m1.length;
        int mRColLength = m2[0].length;
        double[][] mResult = new double[mRRowLength][mRColLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < mRRowLength; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mRColLength; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < m1ColLength; k++) {
                    mResult[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return mResult;
    }

    public static String toString(double[][] m) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                result += String.format("%11.2f", m[i][j]);
            }
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Es tomada de una [publicación de StackOverflow en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623876/matrix-multiplication-using-arrays)